# Bigtable CellsColumnLimitFilter and ValueRangeFilter not working as intended

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm new to Bigtable and I've been testing out the filtering features based on this documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters

I've tried this in this repo under testcsvbigtablefilters.py which I have some problems. For the record, I am testing this on Bigtable Emulator on my local machine
https://github.com/limjix/GoogleCloudBigDataTest

I have some issues with 2 filters:

1. CellsColumnLimitFilter (Line 100-110, uncomment to try)
   This filter doesn't seem to be working. I have a table of 3 columns but when I put CellsColumnLimitFilter(1) or CellsColumnLimitFilter(2), I still get all 3 columns?

```
     rows = table.read_rows(filter_=row_filters.CellsColumnLimitFilter(10))
     for row in rows:
         print_row(row)
```

2. ValueRangeFilter (Line 172-183)
   This filter doesn't work because, for example I have the 1st column with values around 10000 to 14000.
   When I put the start value at 10,000 to 14,000, nothing comes up.
   When I put 0 to 3, the 10k to 14k value start showing up. This makes no sense and the filter does not seem to work at all

```
    rows = table.read_rows(
        filter_=row_filters.ValueRangeFilter(start_value=b'0',end_value=b'3'))

    for row in rows:
        print_row(row)
```

Also, I want to ask, how do I query for cells that have been overwritten? I know bigtable saves the mutation of cells over a period of time. How do I query and filter for a specific time for that cell?

Any help would be appreciated guys, there isn't much tutorials or documentation anywhere else so I hope the community can help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey limjix thanks for the questions! The Bigtable filtering documentation has just been introduced, so questions like this can help us improve it moving forward.

1. `CellsColumnLimitFilter`

The `CellsColumnLimitFilter` limits the number of cells in each column that are included in the output row. In the documentation it is listed as [cells per column filter](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#python), so I can see how this function name would be a bit confusing.

If you only have a row with a few columns that only have one cell or one version for those values, then `CellsColumnLimitFilter` would return all of them. If you're looking to only receive one of the column's data you can use the [`CellsRowLimitFilter`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#cells-per-row-limit) which filters on cells per row. Or you could specify specific columns with any of the column qualifier filters.

2. `ValueRangeFilter`

I did some digging and I believe I know what your issue here is, but I'm not 100%. And am happy to troubleshoot further with you if you need.

It looks like you set the cell values directly from the CSV:

```
bigtablerow.set_cell(column_family_id,
             "column1",
             #str(float(csvrow[20])+i),
             csvrow[20],
             timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

This works fine for string, but if you set a cell value to a number, the python client will treat that as an incrementable value and encode it as a 64-bit big-endian signed integer and will not be comparable with the b'10000' that you have.

For example this code wont return any rows:

```
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
table = instance.table(table_id)

rows = []
for i in range(10):
    row_key = 'test_num{}'.format(i).encode()
    row = table.direct_row(row_key)
    row.set_cell("cf".encode(),
                 "col".encode(),
                 random.randint(10000, 14000)
                 )
    rows.append(row)
table.mutate_rows(rows)


rows = table.read_rows(
    filter_=row_filters.ValueRangeFilter(start_value=b'10000',
                                         end_value=b'14000'))
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

But when I turn the integer into a string I get all the rows

```
    row.set_cell("cf".encode(),
                 "col".encode(),
                 str(random.randint(10000, 14000))
                 )
    rows.append(row)
```

I would recommend using the CBT tool to check out what the data looks like. For example, when I do `cbt read` the first rows look like this:

```
test_num0
  cf:col                                   @ 2020/09/20-22:24:43.835000
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003\xd1"
----------------------------------------
test_num1
  cf:col                                   @ 2020/09/20-22:24:43.835000
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001t"
```

whereas the string ones look like this (they have two values since I used the same rowkeys actually, but you should get the point):

```
test_num0
  cf:col                                   @ 2020/09/20-22:36:12.075000
    "11510"
  cf:col                                   @ 2020/09/20-22:24:43.835000
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003\xd1"
----------------------------------------
test_num1
  cf:col                                   @ 2020/09/20-22:36:12.075000
    "12048"
  cf:col                                   @ 2020/09/20-22:24:43.835000
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001t"
```

3. Querying for cells that have been overwritten

This is similar to what you were trying to do in the first example. For cells that have been overwritten you're looking for filters around cell timestamps ([`TimestampRangeFilter`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#timestamp-range)) or number of cells per column (`CellsColumnLimitFilter` again).

Comment: Thanks Billy! Really appreciate the quick reply and I am totally supporting Google Cloud just because I think Google products rock! 

I have one more follow up question then. How can I simulate a cell being overwritten to have multiple versions then? I've tried doing a for loop on line 35 to 67, meaning I write the values in multiple times but also add to the values  to have a different number. The CellsColumnLimitFilter I think doesn't pick it up still.

Comment: I'm happy to help, I actually wrote all the code you're using and I want to make sure it is understood to make it easier for newcomers to Bigtable. Also, I updated the answer for #2 btw which should help. As for the multiple versions, it should just work automatically if you write to the same table+rowkey+colfamily+column at a timestamp that isn't occupied. You could check you don't have a garbage collection rule preventing more than 1 version. It looks like you have max versions 2 though, so that wouldn't be it. Are you sure you're writing to the same table each time? That could be it

Comment: EDIT: Solution to number 2 works
This works:
str(csvrow[20])

So, it must mean that everything that gets entered into bigtable must be a string?

Comment: One more comment: So filter_=row_filters.ValueRangeFilter(start_value=b'0',end_value=b'12000'))
this still also returns cells from column 2 that have values like 11.2 for example. I assume this has something to do with how the search matches the first few characters?

Comment: Hi Billy, I've just pushed another version on the repo. On question number 3, it doesn't seem to be working. The timestamps are not saved on the emulator eventhough I have specified maxversions as 10

Comment: As for #2, everything in bigtable is written as bytes, but for numbers the python client encodes them as 64-bit big-endian signed integers to make them incrementable. There should be a way to filter on a range of those numbers but I'd need to play around with it more. Feel free to ask more questions about specifics in new threads and mark this as accepted. For the versions, have you tried using the cbt tool to do a `cbt read` on your table and see if there are multiple versions in there? What happens when you overwrite? It changes values or just deletes it?

Comment: @BillyJacobson Landed upon this question for my problem: Does it mean that there is no support for conditional update with integers? Comparison of integers after converting them to string is unreliable due to leading zeroes and other issues.

Comment: No you would be able to conditionally filter with integers you would just need to convert them to the bytes format that matches the one the ints are stored in. I don't think we have a function that does this currently though.